# Como obtener el elemento seleccionado de un combobox usando request, beautifulsoup y python?

Tags: python, scraping, beautifulsoup

Estoy tratando de hacerle scrapping a una web, pude obtener los datos de los textbox pero tengo problema para sacar la informacion de los menus desplegables.

Este es el codigo del menu desplegable:

```
<tr class="FacetFilaTD"><td class="FacetDataTDPADL5">Sexo</td><td colspan="3" 
class="FacetFieldCaptionTD">
<div class="control-valid"><select name="sexo" style="width: 140px; display: none;" id="sexo" 
class="clasecombo_valid" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
<option selected="" value="">[SELECCIONAR]</option><option value="M" 
selected="">Masculino</option><option value="F">Femenino</option></select>

<span><a class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-selectmenu-dropdown ui-state- 
active ui-corner-top" 
id="sexo-button" role="button" href="#nogo" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="sexo- 
menu" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 140px;"><span class="ui-selectmenu- 
status">Masculino</span><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span> 
</a></span><span class="requerido">*</span></div>                                                                      
</td></tr>
```

Y este es mi codigo:

```
login_request = session.post(url,data=payload, headers=headers, 
cookies=cookies)
sexo = BeautifulSoup(login_request.text, 'lxml').select('select[name=sexo] option[selected]') 
[0].value
print(sexo)
```

Al ejecutarlo me devuelve un "None"
Tambien trate de obtener el resultado buscando por las etiquetas span

```
sexo = BeautifulSoup(login_request.text, 'lxml').find("span",id="sexo- 
button").get_text(strip=True)
print(sexo)
```

Pero solo recibi un mensaje de error.
Cual seria la mejor forma de solo imprimir el valor seleccionado, que en este caso es MASCULINO

Comment: Será porque te está devolviendo el primer selected del select el cual no tiene valor

Comment: Encontre la solucion en el siguiente enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73979130/how-to-get-data-from-a-combobox-using-beautifulsoup-and-python/73980579#73980579